# How to remove the rounded menu items from a theme?

Tags: themes

I've just spent quite a while theming ambiance to make it more flat and all around more to my taste, but I've just come across a problem above my capabilities : rounded menuitems

[image]

The menu on the panel have rounded top corners, I'd like to have them squared, a la elementary, but without the effects on the side, since I'm pursuing a flat theme.

I've been looking around in gtk.css and gtk-widgets.css but I can't seem to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

I've performed the following grep on the theme directory:

```
grep -R "border-radius: [0-9]\+px [0-9]\+px 0 0;" /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0
```

It basically searches for "border-radius" followed by any top-left and top-right value.

The result is:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css:    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
```

Inside *gtk-widgets.css* I can see a property called `.menubar.menuitem` which seems what you are looking for. Simply set all `border-radius` values to `0` (px is not needed for value 0).

You can also search for:

```
grep -R "border-radius" /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0
```

Which gives you all occurrences of `border-radius` simplifying your task of flattening the whole theme.